# text_color of a customtkinter widget state disabled

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

excuse my bad English, but I search information about style of custom Kinter widget entry. in standard when the entry or combo box, or textbox is on disabled state, the policy is light Grey, I would like to pass it on a dark policy, and blue policy when they are on a normal state... do you think it's possible?

thanks in advance.